# how to left outer join the query result with another table in Hive

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

I have a table otp_data in hive. I take the average of delay based on carrier name, by using below query

```
select carrier,  avg(ddelay) from otp_data group by carrier;
```

Result:

```
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 28 seconds 980 msec
OK
9E  6.765859659983622
B6  12.653395748122113
DL  8.007765572702564
NW  6.463235656670833
UA  14.11257661236138
US  5.717489671893907
WN  10.383034750411133
AA  13.280898264437912
AS  6.848722010417226
F9  5.919601516833923
```

There is another table called carriers with fields Code and description.

Sample data in carriers:

```
9E , Pinnacle Airlines Inc.
B6 , JetBlue Airways 
---
---
```

I have to print the result(after the join of otp_data and carriers tables like below)

```
Pinnacle Airlines Inc. 6.765859659983622
JetBlue Airways        12.653395748122113
-------
-------
```

Please guide me, how to achieve this in Hive

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
select t2.carrier_desc,  avg(t1.ddelay) 
from otp_data t1 
left outer join carriers t2 
on t1.carrier = t2.carrier
group by t2.carrier_desc;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. It's working.How can we sort the data on the basis of ddelay.

Comment: hi you can not order data basis of ddelay however you can order average of ddelay which is calculated in second column. To do this add "order by 2" script at the end of the query above